# Replace php include with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, include, get

How can I replace a php include navigation with jQuery?

In php I use something like

```
$var = $_GET["site"];
include($var);
```

to get the page to include but how can I do something like this in jQuery? I want to use the URL to get the page.
Is there any combined solution for this problem (probably a fallback if JavaScript is disabled).

```
.load()
```

doesn't manipulate the URL.

Comment: There's not going to be a javascript fall back for javascript being disabled, and you're not going to really have a straight html alternative. I guess you can do iframes or something, seems strange.

Comment: The "disabled jQuery/JavaScript" solution would be server-side code like PHP... which is where you started... which is why this request makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is a [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and provide a callback function to replace the markup on the current page with the markup from the new page.  For this second piece you may be able to use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). If you want to replace the entire page then you should go with something more simple like a [location redirect](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jredir.htm).